# Advantage of registering USB endpoint as device

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, libusb

I have a question regarding registering endpoints as real device. What is the advantage of registering USB device endpoints as a real device?

```
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/usb/core/endpoint.c?h=v5.4.84#n176
```

While searching the changes, it seems initially USB device endpoints are registered as kobjects.

My understand is if we register USB device endpoint as real device then it will create attribute files under sysfs(In my Ubuntu PC : /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-10:1.0/ep_81/). Correct me if this is not correct. If we add using kobjects then also attribute files will be created in sysfs.

My question here is what is the advantage of registering endpoints as real device or what is the problem in adding endpoints as kobjects(which solves when we register as real device).

Comment: Because endpoints can provide a functionality to other devices in the system. For example, how you can provide a firmware nodes and properties for the kobjects?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. I think during enumeration based on vendor and product id, class/functionality driver will bind with the device. My question is advantage of registering USB device endpoints as a real device instead of kobject.
My understanding is, each USB interface provides functionality and interface contains group of endpoints. Can you please guide me to understand for a USB device, say if we connect a USB-to-Ethernet adapter and the adapter is having 3 end points then what is the advantage of registering 3 end points as real devices instead adding 3 end points as kobjects.

Comment: Greg KH's rationale from 2006 was *This will allow for us to give endpoints a major/minor to create a "usbfs2-like" way to access endpoints directly from userspace in an easier manner than the current usbfs provides us.* ([commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=9bde7497e0b54178c317fac47a18be7f948dd471)) I don't know if any userspace libraries such as libusb actually use them though.

Comment: It seems major and minor numbers are not filled in "struct device" member of ["struct ep_device"](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/usb/core/endpoint.c?h=v5.4.84#n20) before [calling device_register()](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/usb/core/endpoint.c?h=v5.4.84#n196). So I think device_register() will not create file for endpoint under /dev/, is it correct? Can you help in getting usbfs2 source. I searched in internet for source, but didn't find any source code repository.